# How to return the print function "You win" after user guess wrong on first guess but enters correctly after

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

So i am tryting to create a number guessing game. If they user inputs the first try then it prints "You win!" as wanted. When they enter incorrectly it prompts them to try again, however when guessed correctly after the first time then it keeps prompting them. How do I make it so it prints "You win"!

```
if play == "Y":
    print("Great! Lets play")
    guess = int(input("I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20\nWhat is your first guess? "))
    while guess != number:
        guess = input("Guess again: ")
    if guess == number:
        print("You win!")
```

Comment: You don’t need that `if` statement after the `while` loop. Is this all your code? Where is `number` defined? See: [mcve].

Comment: You need to call `int()` when you ask the user to guess again, just like you do when you ask for the first number.

Comment: @Barmar That worked! Thank you